# Error when running a macro if open a different workbook is open

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I was wondering if anybody could help me, I have (below) code in a module, however, if I am currently in a different open workbook an error message pops up. I am guessing it is trying to execute the macro in the current selected workbook instead of the needed workbook ("MKL").
Below is the code.

```
Dim TimeToRun

Sub auto_open()
    Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver
End Sub

Sub ScheduleCopyPriceOver()
    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CopyPriceOver"
End Sub

Sub CopyPriceOver()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim celltxt As String
    Calculate
    Workbooks("MKL.xlsm").Sheets("Data Quarter Hourly").Select
    Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver
    Workbooks("MKL.xlsm").Sheets("Data Quarter Hourly").Rows("9:9").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Workbooks("MKL.xlsm").Sheets("Data Quarter Hourly").Range("DateNow:Stock2").Copy
    Workbooks("MKL.xlsm").Sheets("Data Quarter Hourly").Range("A9:C9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D10:CB10").Copy
    Workbooks("MKL.xlsm").Sheets("Data Quarter Hourly").Range("D9:CB9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
    celltxt = Workbooks("MKL.xlsm").Sheets("Trades").Range("C2").Text
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "A") Or InStr(1, celltxt, "B") Then
        MyPath = "Z:\capital\Research - internal\Arb Trading Models\Trades"
        MyFileName = "Trades " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
        If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".xls" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".xls"
        Workbooks("MKL.xlsm").Sheets("Trades").Copy
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:= _
                MyPath & MyFileName, _
                Local:=True, _
                FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal, _
                CreateBackup:=False
            .Close False
        End With
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub auto_close()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CopyPriceOver", , False
End Sub
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message? At which point is it throwing the error?

Comment: The error is: "Run-time error '1004': Select method of worksheet class failed." And it happens on the minute only if I am in another workbook at the point in time when the code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a few things that could throw off your code due to implicit references.

I went through the CopyPriceOver and replaced the implicit reference with a more explicit one, useda worksheet and workbbok objects and added a few comments:

```
Sub CopyPriceOver()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim celltxt As String
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("MKL.xlsm") '<~~ we set a workbook object wb to the workbook "MKL.xlsm", this will save us a lot of writin and improve readability
    Dim wsDataQuarterHourly As Worksheet: Set wsDataQuarterHourly = wb.Worksheets("Data Quarter Hourly") '<~~ set a worksheet object to reference the "Data Quarter Hourly" sheet in the MKL.xlsm workbook, by use of the above wb object
    Dim wsTrades As Worksheet: Set wsTrades = wb.Worksheets("Trades") '<~~ set a worksheet object to reference the "Trades" sheet in in the MKL.xlsm workbook

    Calculate
    wsDataQuarterHourly.Select '<~~ i don't see the need to select it? I may be completely wrong, but if omitted what happens to your execution?
    Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver
    wsDataQuarterHourly.Rows("9:9").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove '<~~ using the worksheet object
    wsDataQuarterHourly.Range("DateNow:Stock2").Copy '<~~ I was not aware you could reference ranges like that? and it not working on my end
    wsDataQuarterHourly.Range("A9:C9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
    'Next line should be updated
    Range("D10:CB10").Copy '<~~ what do you want to copy? if from the "Data Quarter Hourly" then wsDataQuarterHourly.Range("D10:CB10")

    wsDataQuarterHourly.Range("D9:CB9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
    celltxt = wsTrades.Range("C2").Text
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "A") Or InStr(1, celltxt, "B") Then
        MyPath = "Z:\capital\Research - internal\Arb Trading Models\Trades"
        MyFileName = "Trades " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
        If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".xls" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".xls"
        wsTrades.Copy '<~~ why copy? I don't see it used?
        With wb '<~~ explicit reference to the "MKL.xlsm" workbook
            .SaveAs Filename:= _
                MyPath & MyFileName, _
                Local:=True, _
                FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal, _
                CreateBackup:=False
            .Close False
        End With
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

in the code above, and in your own, You should pay special attention to the line:

```
    Range("D10:CB10").Copy
```

It implicitly implies the range D10:CB10 in the ActiveSheet of the ActiveWorkbook. If you working in a different workbook, it would reference D10:CB10 in what ever sheet is active in that WorkBook. While that may not cause an error I doubt it was intended.

Also, when you save the Workbook you referenced the ActiveWorkbook, which again would be the one you are working in.

I had some issues with a line that copies a *.Range("DateNow:Stock2"), that I have no idea what should be why I have not properly tested the code

Answer (score 0):

Presumably 'ScheduleCopyPriceOver' is defined in a module in  Workbook 'MKL.xlsm'?

Try using `Workbooks("MKL.xlsm").Sheets("Data Quarter Hourly").Activate` and putting the Sub 'ScheduleCopyPriceOver' into the "MKL.xlsm", ThisWorkbook module in the 'Sub Workbook_Activate()' event.

Don't forget to comment-out the existing Call in `Sub CopyPriceOver()`

Comment: Thanks for your insight Barry I will try and revert back to you, regarding your earlier question I have no idea how to answer it as I am a newbie and everything there is pieced together from other codes found online.